# How compare two arrays and count equal items in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, compare

I have two arrays: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} and {1, 3, 3, 6, 5}.

To find out ho many items that are similar (in same position) I do like this:

```
int[] a = new int[5] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] b = new int[5] {1, 3, 3, 6, 5};
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if(a[i] == b[i])
      count++;
}
Console.Write(count);
```

This will give the result 3.

Is there a better (faster) way to do this?

Comment: You can convolute that to make it less code, but unless there's a good reason I'd say don't bother.  It's fine as it is and does exactly what you need in a very clear manner.

Comment: @Archer how about the danger of a `IndexOutOfRangeException` in case of `b.Length > a.Length` - beside that, I would avoid to iterate to a fix value

Comment: I recommend you add something like `int n = Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length)` and then make the `for` loop look like: `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)`. Other than that, your code is likely to be optimal in terms of readability and performance.

Comment: @fubo There's a lot of hard-coded values in this example that shouldn't be there.  This is clearly an example of an issue and not production code.

Answer (score 1):

Linq `Zip()` is one way

```
int equalElements = a.Zip(b, (i, j) => i == j).Count(eq => eq);
```

Comment: One-liner and some security (index and bounds) is good, but not making intent so obscure. This code wouldn't pass most of code-reviews, should rather be a custom method, similar to [SequenceEqual implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,920).

Answer (score 0):

Building on the `Zip` solution, but aiming for better readability there's:

```
int[] a = new int[5] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] b = new int[5] {1, 3, 3, 6, 5};

var count = a.Zip(b, (x, y) => (X : x, Y : y))
            .Where(t => t.X == t.Y)
            .Count();
```

This works by combing both arrays into a single sequence of tuples `(X, Y)` and then using `Where` to only select the tuples where `X` and `Y` are equal.

You'll need to ensure you have a reference to the `System.ValueTuple` assembly for this to work.